# Azure DevOps Permissions for Individual Repositories

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Let's say I have created a new project (MyProject) on ADO.  In it, I have 2 repositories (MyRepo1 and MyRepo2).  I would like to invite another user to contribute code to MyRepo1, but don't want them seeing MyRepo2.  How can this be done?

I have tried creating a team (Team1) for MyRepo1 and adding the user to that team.  However, they still cannot see anything in ADO under my project.  If I add them to the default team of the project, they can see all the repos (bad).  This is how I set up Team1:

[image]

As an aside, if anyone knows of a good comprehensive reference for the proper way of using and orchestrating Organizations, Projects, Teams, Areas, Azure DevOps Groups, Users, Repositories, etc., please let me know.  Each time I think I have these things under control, I get stuck in some scenario like this one.  Add in Azure AD and Azure Subscriptions, and things get pretty hairy sometimes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I came here because I had the same challenge, and wanted to present my solution, in case others have found themselves in the same situation.

First go to Project Settings | Permissions and add a new group for the selected users.
Choose the newly created group and set Allow in 'View project-level information'.

Back in Project Settings click Repositories and click the Repository, you want to grant access to. Click Permissions and search for the new group. Set Allow in relevant permissions (for me it was Contribute, Contribute to pull requests, Create branch, Create tag, Manage notes, and Read).

The users in this group can see the project overview, but no pipelines and only the selected repository.

You do not need to worry that repositories added later will be visible to this group either.

Comment: It is indeed old, but I gave up on solving it because it seemed what I was trying to do was simply not supported.  I appreciate the contribution and will aim to implement it soon, and mark this answer as accepted if it works for me.

Comment: Well, I tried it today, and as far as we can tell, your approach has worked.  I'll accept the answer, and I'm really grateful that you took the time to do this.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to invite another user to contribute code to MyRepo1, but
>   don't want them seeing MyRepo2. How can this be done?

The place you configured permissions is correct, but it seems you've set the wrong permission.

If you want to ensure that users in **Team1** can contribute to **MyRepos1**, but cannot view **MyRepos2**, then, in the project settings page, go to **MyRepos2-> Team1**, and set the **Read** permission to Deny. This setting means "do not allow Team1 members to have read permissions for MyRepos2."

The configuration should look like this:

[image]

After this adjustment, the members of Team1 will not be able to see MyRepos2. When attempting to open MyRepos2, they will see the message below;

[image]

> a good comprehensive reference for the proper way of using and
>   orchestrating Organizations, Projects, Teams, Areas, Azure DevOps
>   Groups, Users, Repositories, etc

That is a large range of material.  I can't give you such a reference. I can just share some of my experience with you.

---

(1) If you want to set the user's permission to access some projects, just go to the **Users** tab on the **Organization Settings** page, click the ellipsis icon, and choose **Manage Projects**:

[image]

---

(2) In the **Permissions** tab of the **Organization Settings** page, you can set permissions which affect the whole organization, including all projects/repos.

---

For any specific object permission (build, workitem, etc.), just go to the corresponding object and configure it.

In the docs, we offer precise permission setting descriptions.  You can refer to them here:

[Permissions and groups in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

[Permissions lookup guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions-lookup-guide?view=azure-devops)

If these are not enough for you, just share your problems or questions here. Maybe I can advise you further.

Comment: Hmmm.  With this solution, wouldn't that mean that for any additional repositories that could be added, I'd have to configure the DENY permission for Team1 for each one of them (assuming Team1 should only see that one repo)?  Further, wouldn't the DENY permission make it so that I myself couldn't see the repo, were I on that team?

Comment: @bubbleking You just need to configure the team’s permission is ok. It will affect the everyone in this team. So, anyone in this team include you, will all could not see the repo which the read set as deny.

Comment: This is not a solution to the question asked - it's a workaround.
As @bubbleking states, in a project with a hundred repos, it would not be feasible to deny access to 'all the others'