# Azure Devops permission for some repositories

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

We have an Azure Devops Project with several repositories.
However we only want to give access to a couple of repos to another team.

I've setup a group called `Outsource` (oddly it doesn't show under Project Settings > General > Teams) and within the Project Settings > Repos > Repositories section i've given the group permissions.

However they can't access theses repos from My Org > Repos (red icon).
Also they can't clone the repos either.

The one user in the 'Outsource' group is setup  as a basic user.

Can anyone tell if I'm missing a setting? It doesn't seem like providing permission against a repo does anything?
I also gave them access to a different project and they can access that fine.

Comment: I have seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599721/azure-devops-permissions-for-individual-repositories but the ui is different now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Stakeholder user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#stakeholder-access) cannot access private project repo.
The permission group Outsource is collection level group, we recommend that you open the project settings and create a project level permission group and add these users.
[image]

Configure permission

Open project settings-> Repositories->click one repo-> select the repositories which you want to give access to another team->add the permission group and set the permission Read to Allow. Then the group users can access these repositories.

[image]

Select the repositories which you do not want to give access to another team->add the permission group and set the permission Read to Deny. Then the group users cannot access these repositories.

[image]

Comment: Thanks could I set all repos to deny and then individual ones to read ?

Comment: In Azure DevOps, Deny having the highest level, and it can override all allow permissions. You need to configure the permission in each repository.

Comment: According to the docs, stakeholder users have _no_ access to repos. Can that be changed using this approach? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/stakeholder-access?view=azure-devops

Comment: @span: No! "If they need to contribute to the code base, then you must assign them Basic or higher-level access". I can confirm that for our repo.

Comment: @JMWC2019: You can go to Project settings -> Repositories and NOT select a repository. Then "Security" tab and set general permissions for the project. There you can set Deny (for all) and then allow individual repos as described above.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-git-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops
Fyi, I had to allow all to make it work for an individual permissions group...

Comment: I don't understand your last step. If there is 1 person in the group "outsource" and that group is only associated to 1 repo. then why do you need to explicitly explain other repos with that group and set to deny? Doesn't the fact that those other groups aren't apart of the other repositories would inherently not have access to those repositories? It seems like an unnecessary redundant step.

Answer (score -2):

Your users are currently experiencing difficulties with cloning or accessing repositories, as evidenced by a red icon. Moreover, they're unable to clone repositories successfully. However, I can provide you with a comprehensive explanation of how to resolve this issue. Dont Worry.

So first step is which you already did is making an organization.

now you have to give access to users so they have the option of red icon for Repos. there are several steps given below.

1. from the left bottom corner click on Organization
   settings. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzfF3.png
2. Navigate to the left sidebar and locate the 'General' section. Within this section, you'll find the 'Users' option. Click on it to proceed.
3. You will find a user list where you can both add new users and update existing ones. In either scenario, once a new user is added or an existing user is updated, make sure to set their permissions to the 'Basic' level. This will enable the user to view the Repos with the red icon button.

The user now has access to the 'Repos' section. Furthermore, it's time to configure the user's permissions, granting them access to specific repositories or all repositories.

1. Next, enter the Organization you've created, and in the bottom-left corner, click on 'Project settings' in the left-hand corner.
2. Within it, navigate to the 'Repos' section, and then proceed to click on 'Repositories.' This action will open the 'Repositories' tab, followed by the adjacent 'Security' tab.
3. Select the repository to which you intend to grant user access. Once selected, navigate to the 'Security' tab located at the top. Here, you'll find the sections for both groups and users. At the upper portion, an input field is available for adding a user by either email or username. After entering the user's information and clicking on it, they will be promptly added.
   On the right-hand side, a range of permissions will be presented, allowing you to choose specific access levels for the user.

Your user now possesses the necessary access and can commence work within the designated repository they've been granted access to. I've aimed to keep the instructions straightforward, hoping they prove beneficial to you.

Comment: You clearly don't have the slightest idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I have a solid understanding of the topic, but your perspective may differ. If you're new to Azure DevOps, that could explain any uncertainties. Additionally, it's possible you're not familiar with the specific permissions involved.

Regarding the user group creation, that was explained earlier. The questionnaire mentioned an issue with accessing repositories in 'My Org > Repos' and the appearance of a red icon. To address this, ensure the user's access level is set to 'Basic' through organization user settings.

Comment: If they didn't have basic level, they wouldn't be able to see the red "Repos" icon at all, and they wouldn't be able to access repos in other projects in that org, either.